# How can I consolidate duplicate entries in iTunes without losing statistical data?

Tags: itunes, deduplication

I recently combined two of my PCs in a Frankensteinian attempt to optimize my hardware configuration. One of these PCs was much older and had a different collection of music on it than my current one does; now that I've got both hard drives available at the same time, though, I thought I'd update my directory tree and moved all my music to a new folder on my desktop. Then I added that folder to my iTunes library.

The result, of course, was a huge list of songs duplicated two or three times. One or two of the entries usually pointed to an incorrect location, though, and I couldn't figure out how to delete them en masse, so instead I clicked on the "correct location" for one such file and asked iTunes to use that information to locate other missing files. Rather than consolidating my entries, it's now just turned all those previously invalid songs into perfect duplicates—except that none of the "new" songs have any of my rating or times played information. Observe:

[image: screenshot of iTunes]
 (Forgive the poor quality screenshot; an old issue with Windows causes all black text to appear as white whenever I use Print Screen to save a screenshot.)

Normally I'd just delete all the songs that haven't been heard, except that some subset of those are legitimately new songs to this computer. Is there any way for me to get iTunes to figure out which ones are "new" copies and just get rid of those?

(Yes, this is similar to existing questions, but every one I found was a less "complete" question, and didn't have as exacting demands as I needed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at a combination of Doug's scripts.

- Use this script to set the last played date.
  http://dougscripts.com/itunes/scripts/ss.php?sp=newlastplayed
- And this script to set the play count
  http://dougscripts.com/itunes/scripts/ss.php?sp=newlastplayed

However this is a very manual operation. If you put a bounty on the question someone might write an Applescript to do it.

Comment: I'm going to consider "pay rep to have someone build a script to do it for you" the correct answer to my original question, although actually I wound up just turning on a podcast and deleted nearly a thousand entries by hand.